# Material Design Toolbar CustomView RelativeLayout

Tags: android-layout, material-design

RelativeLayout doesn't seem to play nice in the v7 support library.  I have three elements, One is aligned to the bottom and the other two stack above it.  Rather than appear nicely stacked at the bottom, they are rendered off screen, this is unexpected.

I've included an example XML file which is for the custom view added to the toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:layout_above="@+id/divider"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textColor="@color/textLighter"
        android:text="@string/example_sequence_name"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/textLighter"
        android:layout_above="@+id/description"
        android:layout_height="81dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_description"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"
        android:textColor="@color/textLighter"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:singleLine="true" />
```

Results in this view. 
[image]

Comment: could it be something to do with content inset?